The Flutter Daemon failed to start and Unable to find Git in your path error in VS Code
I’m experiencing an issue while working with Flutter in VS Code. When I open my project in normal mode, I get the following error message:
The Flutter Daemon failed to start.
when I try to run any commands such as flutter pub get, I receive this error:
Unable to find the git in your path.
However, if I open VS Code in Administrator mode, everything works fine, and the errors don’t appear.
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
VS Code Version: 1.94.2
Node.js: 20.16.0
Flutter 3.24.3
Dart SDK version: 3.5.3
git version 2.43.0.windows.1
I have already tried manually writing the gitpath in setting.json but it doesn't work.
i have tried to reinstalled my vs code but still same issue.

I think you missed to add flutter path to your system
add flutter bin path to your paths under System Variables
simply open Edit Envoirment Variable window
under the System Variables find Key value pair key name Path
edit it and past you flutter bin path there
than just restart you system

I have already written flutter path in system variable but still facing problem.

make sure your have placed the correct path

Yeah, its working now.  First I wrote the wrong path. i have write the flutter path instead of flutter/bin.
